# Unknown tag (fmt:formatNumber)

Tags: jsp

Eclipse had this compilation error:

> Unknown tag (fmt:formatNumber)

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${product.price}" type="currency" currencyCode="USD" /></td>
```

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the top of jsp page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```